# How to link to other page tab in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, tabs

I had a list of tab on view_profil page:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="mytab">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#profil">Profil</a></li>
  <li><a id="keluarga-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#keluarga">Keluarga</a></li>
  <li><a id="kursus-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#kursus">Kursus</a></li>
  <li><a id="akademik-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#akademik">Akademik</a></li>
  <li><a id="anugerah-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#anugerah">Anugerah</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to link a button from other page to this page but referring to 'keluarga' tab directly.

I used this code for the button:

```
<a href="{{ url('/view_profil/' . $valueItemregistrationkeluarga->ItemRegistrationID.'#keluarga') }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-md">Back</a>
```

I had tried using a few jquery code and javascript but fail..What is the right javascript/jquery for this purpose?

This is jquery used ;

```
<script>
var hash = document.location.hash;
if (hash) {
$('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
} 

// Change hash for page-reload
$('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
});
</script>
```

I have tried your solutions without tabs:

```
 <script>
 var hash = document.location.hash;
 if (hash) {
 $('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']').tab('show');
 } 

 // Change hash for page-reload
 $('.nav a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
 window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
 });
 </script>
```

I also tried this code:

Try1:

```
    // Javascript to enable link to tab
    var url = document.location.toString();
    if (url.match('#')) {
      $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + url.split('#')[1] + '"]').tab('show');
   } 

 // Change hash for page-reload
  $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  window.location.hash = e.target.hash;
  })
```

Try 2:
     var openTab = $(location.hash).filter(".tab_content");

```
 if(openTab.length){
 $("a[href='"+location.hash+"']").click();
 }
```

Try 3:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 (function activateTabFromHash() { if (location.hash) { var tabLink = document.querySelector('a[href="' + location.hash + '"]'); if (!tabLink) { return false; } tabLink.click(); if (location.hash) {
  setTimeout(function() {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, 1);
  } } })();
  </script>
```

I am using laravel 5 for this application.

The button can link to the page but it doesn't activate the specified tab.

Comment: Try putting the href value in quotation marks in the jQuery selector, e.g. `$('.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]')`.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand. Can you answer and explain a little bit..If it is working, I can accept your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JQuery seems to expect the value of `href` to be in quotes(`""`), for example `href="#keluarga"`.

Currently, the part where you are selecting the tab (`$('.nav-tabs a[href='+hash+']')`) would result in `'.nav-tabs a[href=#keluarga]` if `hash='#keluarga'`. JQuery throws a syntax exception because the `=` sign is followed by a `#` and not a `"`.

Therefore, ensure that the value of `hash` is wrapped in quotes. You can change that part of your code to: `$('.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash+'"]')`.

Comment: i have tried that, the error is gone but it redirect to the page without navigating to the specified tab.

Comment: Try surrounding the code inside with `$( document ).ready()`. You can read up about it at http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: I am sorry but it is still not working.. I am also lost where to find the solution..already tried a lot..don't know why it is not working

Comment: Post what else you've tried, otherwise there's no way anyone can assist you.

Comment: Also, I don't see any `nav-tabs` class in your html, but you're trying to select it with JQuery. Try `$('.nav a[href="'+hash+'"]')` instead.